# Django admin encoding error

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models, python-3.x, django-admin

I am trying to add new user with admin interface and get this error:

> IntegrityError at /admin/main/customuser/add/
>
> ������������:  INSERT ������ UPDATE �� ��������������
>   "django_admin_log" ���������������� ����������������������
>   ���������������� ���������� "django_admin_log_user_id_fkey"  DETAIL: 
>   �������� (user_id)=(1) ���������������������� �� ��������������
>   "auth_user".

Here is **traceback**:

```
     File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 372, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 202, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 223, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 217, in __exit__
    self.exiting(exc_value, self.using)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 281, in exiting
    commit(using=using)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 152, in commit
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 241, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 328, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py", line 240, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
```

I am using **Postgres** with **psycopg2** and cant understand where is problem. On **django** side, on **Postgres** or may be in **psycopg2**?

Also when I am logging to admin again, it was responsde that user have been added successfully, but there is no new users in database table.

Comment: May be it wiil help, but if i run syncdb command on blank database, it doesnt create 2 tables: auth_users and auth_user_groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't solve problem with encoding in database response, but i've solved problem in general. I added custom auth backend and no more error messages from database. Here my example backend that solve the problem:

```
class CustomBackend (ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            try:
                user = CustomUser.objects.get(id = kwargs['id'])
            except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
                #print ("WE ARE HERE!", kwargs)
                user = CustomUser(nickName=kwargs['nickName'], id=kwargs['id'])
                user.reputation = 0
                user.save()
            return user
        if username == 'admin' and password == 'admin':
            return CustomUser.objects.get(nickName='m9')

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```